# Matlab draw 'subaxis' based subplots on specified 'axes'

Tags: matlab, user-interface, subfigure

I am coding some GUI staff using Matlab. And I want to plot a figure with subfigures in one specified 'axes' using 'subaxis' method (which can be download on Matlab FX [subaxis.m](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot)).

The program behaves quite right at first. As the subfigures are updating by one click button. Then the error pops-up. I simplify the problem and write some testing codes as following:

```
% Specify an 'axes' in my GUI (here is an example of axes handle called 'ax')
ax = axes;
axes(ax); 
cla(ax, 'reset');

% Plot something using 'subaxis' with multiple subfigures 
x = 0:0.1:10;
spacing = 0.0;
subaxis(3,1,1,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'k')
legend('D','Location','NorthWest')
ylim([-0.2 1])
set(gca, 'box','off')
set(gca,'XAxisLocation','top')

subaxis(2,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'r')
legend('C','Location','NorthWest')
ylim([-0.2 1])
set(gca,'xtick',[],'box','off','xcolor','w')

subaxis(3,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'b')
legend('B','Location','NorthWest')
set(gca, 'box','off')
```

The program is fine at this point and did what I expected. Now I press a button to update these subfigures, but still want to plot the subfigures in the specified axes called 'ax':

```
axes(ax); 
cla(ax, 'reset');

x = 0:0.1:10;
spacing = 0.0;
subaxis(3,1,1,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'k')
legend('D','Location','NorthWest')
ylim([-0.2 1])
set(gca, 'box','off')
set(gca,'XAxisLocation','top')

subaxis(2,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'r')
legend('C','Location','NorthWest')
ylim([-0.2 1])
set(gca,'xtick',[],'box','off','xcolor','w')

subaxis(3,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'b')
legend('B','Location','NorthWest')
set(gca, 'box','off')
```

Error shows up!!!

```
Error using axes
Invalid object handle
```

Not sure what to do as the error info is so brief. It seems the subaxis can only be plot to a specific 'axes' once.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks very much. A.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines from the top of your second piece of code:

```
axes(ax); 
cla(ax, 'reset');
```

Now matlab will update the graph in the current plot. I have tested this in a normal (non-GUI) matlab file and it works fine. If it doesn't work for you, post details of the GUI as there may be some related problem within.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is I can't remove the first two lines. As this is a simplified version of my GUI. I need to plot the 'subaxis' (which contains subfigures) in one specified 'axes' (for example, 'ax' here in the example). In my GUI there are ax_1, ax_2, ... ax_n. I use the axes(ax) command to designate 'ax' is the current axes showing the plot.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you should post the full or relevant parts of the GUI code here.